# Symfony2 UniqueEntity validation error with entity inheritance

Tags: validation, inheritance, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a patner, a buyer and an admin class that inherit a user class

When I want to add a partner, the validator do not work

```
 * @DoctrineAssert\UniqueEntity(fields="username", message="Ce nom d'utilisateur est déjà utilisé, veuillez en choisir un autre.", groups={"registration", "account"})
 * @DoctrineAssert\UniqueEntity(fields="mail", message="Cette adresse mail est déjà utilisé, veuillez en choisir un autre.", groups={"registration", "account"})
```

If I choose a username to a "partner" that is already in database, it shows me the right validation error. But if I choose the username of a "buyer" which is already in the database, there is no verification, and have a unique field error in my databases.

Class User

```
<?php

namespace Antho\Test\CoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints as DoctrineAssert;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\MessageDigestPasswordEncoder;

/**
 * Antho\Test\CoreBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Antho\Test\CoreBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"user" = "User", "partner" = "Partner", "buyer" = "Buyer", "admin" = "Admin"})
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @DoctrineAssert\UniqueEntity(fields="username", message="Ce nom d'utilisateur est déjà utilisé, veuillez en choisir un autre.", groups={"registration", "account"})
 * @DoctrineAssert\UniqueEntity(fields="mail", message="Cette adresse mail est déjà utilisé, veuillez en choisir un autre.", groups={"registration", "account"})
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $username
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string $lastName
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="last_name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @var string $firstName
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @var string $mail
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="mail", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $mail;

    /**
     * @var string $password
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $password;


    public function __construct()
    {
        if ($this->createdAt === null) {
            $this->createdAt = new \DateTime('now');
        }
        $this->isEnabled = true;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    GETTER and SETTER ...
}
```

Class Partner

```
<?php

namespace Antho\Test\CoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints as DoctrineAssert;

/**
 * Antho\Test\CoreBundle\Entity\Partner
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="partner")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Antho\Test\CoreBundle\Entity\PartnerRepository")
 */
class Partner extends User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Restaurant", mappedBy="partner", cascade={"remove", "persist"})
     */
    private $restaurants;

    /**
     * @var string $company
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="company", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $company;


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->restaurants = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->isValid = false;
    }

    GETTER and SETTER ...
}
```

Class Buyer

```
<?php

namespace Antho\Test\CoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints as DoctrineAssert;

/**
 * Antho\Test\CoreBundle\Entity\Buyer
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="buyer")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Antho\Test\CoreBundle\Entity\BuyerRepository")
 */
class Buyer extends User
{
    /**
     * @var string $address
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $address;

    /**
     * @var string $city
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @var string $zip
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="zip", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $zip;

    /**
     * @var boolean $newsletter
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="newsletter", type="boolean")
     */
    private $newsletter;


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        if ($this->newsletter === null) {
            $this->newsletter = false;
        }
    }

    GETTER and SETTER ...
}
```

Comment: This seems to be OK. My only guess that annotation is not being recognized. Try to do it like they did in the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html

Comment: The validator do not work. I think there's a problem with inheritance

Comment: "Single Table Inheritance is an inheritance mapping strategy where all classes of a hierarchy are mapped to a **single** database table". You seem to be trying to use a different table for each class?

Comment: no, I use the same table for every class

Comment: I think @Cerad is right. I mean, look at the `@Table` annotations. They all point to different name....

Comment: Ok but if I write @Table(). Same result, the validator do not work.

Comment: what about if you remove the table annotation... you certainly don't need that

Comment: Mikhail: for a similar issue, write a custom validator specific to these classes to check if the field (for instance "username") is unique. Copy/Paste the UniqueEntity class as UniqueUserEntity or something and modify it to check the type as well (patner, buyer or admin).

Answer (score 5):

This is an old unanswered question, however people still might face this issue. And this might help and save their time.

The problem is that UniqueEntityValidator by default takes only current (the one which is checking) entity's repository. In other words, if you submit Partner, it checks only Partner entries. It doesn't take into account other entites, such as Buyer or User in your "single_table" inheritance mapping.

To solve your problem, you can just add to your annotation `entityClass` attribute with your parent class name:

```
@DoctrineAssert\UniqueEntity(fields="username", message="Ce nom d'utilisateur est déjà utilisé, veuillez en choisir un autre.", groups={"registration", "account"}, entityClass="Antho\Test\CoreBundle\Entity\User")
```

This part **entityClass="Antho\Test\CoreBundle\Entity\User"** actually solves your problem.

In this case validator will go through all your user entries (including its child entries too).

Comment: Thanks @Tomas, this was the solution for my issue as well. I have a User class and a Member class which extends the User class. When I'd like to create a Member obj, the validation now works.

Comment: this should be an accepted answer, exactly answers the question

Comment: Thanks, this helped me, see the doc about this option: https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html#entityclass

Answer (score 1):

My two cents. Not pretend to be the right answer.

Remove all unneeded `@Table` from the subclasses and make fields visible (`protected`). I did quite the same (with Symfony 2.0.x) and it works like a charm.

It's slightly different from your code, here a tag (or a keyword) name is unique for each user. But you can test it anyways:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(
 *     name="meta",
 *     uniqueConstraints={
 *         @ORM\UniqueConstraint(columns={"name", "user_id", "type"})
 *     },
 *     indexes={
 *         @ORM\index(columns={"description"}),
 *         @ORM\index(columns={"type"})
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"tag" = "Tag", "keyword" = "Keyword"})
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"name", "user"})
 */
abstract class Meta
{
    protected $name;

    protected $user;
}
```

Child classes:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Tag extends Meta { }

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Keyword extends Meta { }
```